# re.sub in python sometimes do not work

Tags: python, regex

I have the following spanish sentence.

> Oye , si te parece quedamos en El Corte Inglés de Nuevos Ministerios este martes , a las 18:30 , y me ayudas con las compras , te parece los sofás no sé si comprarlos en Zara Home o en la web , que es http://zara-home.es . De todas maneras , dame un toque al +00 000 000 000 y lo hablamos. Te dejo también mi correo , username@domain .com. Venga , hasta luego.

From this sentence, I want to remove the spaces between 'words and commas' and 'words and fullstops'. I am using the following code to do this job. It works for most other sentences, But do not work for the said sentence.

```
sentence = 'Oye , si te parece quedamos en El Corte Inglés de Nuevos Ministerios este martes , a las 18:30 , y me ayudas con las compras , te parece los sofás no sé si comprarlos en Zara Home o en la web , que es http://zara-home.es . De todas maneras , dame un toque al +00 000 000 000 y lo hablamos. Te dejo también mi correo , username@domain .com. Venga , hasta luego.'
full_stop = re.compile(u"(?<=\s)([\w\d\@\-\:\/\.]+\s[\.,])", re.UNICODE)
words_changed = ["".join(full_stops.split()) for full_stops in full_stop.findall(sentence)]
for i,words in enumerate(full_stop.findall(sentence)):
    words = re.sub('\s.','\s\.',words, flags=re.UNICODE)
    sentence = re.sub(words, words_changed[i], sentence, flags=re.UNICODE)
print sentence
```

Why does the re.sub do not always act, the way it is supposed to in python?

Comment: You *do* know that isn't a `unicode`, right?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: FYI it's not very nice to post others' phone numbers or email addresses.  Even if it's your own, you should remove personal info.

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo: I think the phone number should be not be turned into `#`, but by faking a number (e.g. 0000000)

Comment: @nhahtdh it's immaterial in this case, but if he were matching on digits explicitly (and not grouping them with other characters which # also matches on) then yes I agree

Comment: It gives the same sentence as output, without any modifications and I use Python 2.7

Comment: @dbaupp: Obviously it's Python 2 (`print` statement and Unicode literals).

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo: It seems that `#` may change how the regex operates. I haven't looked carefully at what it code does, but the regex specifies the characters to be matched (whitelisting), so it may change the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you need?

```
>>> s = u'Oye , si te parece quedamos en El Corte Inglés de Nuevos Ministerios este martes , a las 18:30 , y me ayudas con las compras , te parece los sofás no
sé si comprarlos en Zara Home o en la web , que es http://zara-home.es . De todas maneras , dame un toque al +00 000 000 000 y lo hablamos. Te dejo también mi c
orreo , username@domain .com. Venga , hasta luego.'
>>> import re
>>> s = re.sub(r'\s+([,.])', r'\1', s)
>>> print s
Oye, si te parece quedamos en El Corte Inglés de Nuevos Ministerios este martes, a las 18:30, y me ayudas con las compras, te parece los sofás no sé si comprarl
os en Zara Home o en la web, que es http://zara-home.es. De todas maneras, dame un toque al +00 000 000 000 y lo hablamos. Te dejo también mi correo, username@d
omain.com. Venga, hasta luego.
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

```
for i, words in enumerate(full_stop.findall(sentence)):
    word = re.sub('\s\.','\s\.', words, flags=re.UNICODE)
    word = re.sub('\s\,','\s\,', word, flags=re.UNICODE)
    sentence = re.sub(word, words_changed[i], sentence, flags=re.UNICODE)
print sentence
```

however your original regex doesnt detect the first word: 'Oye ,'

Answer (score 0):

You regex looks overly complicated. Here's one that works:

```
>>> sentence = "Oye , si te parece quedamos en El Corte Inglés de Nuevos Ministerios este martes , a las 18:30 , y me ayudas con las compras , te parece los sofás no sé si comprarlos en Zara Home o en la web , que es http://zara-home.es . De todas maneras , dame un toque al +00 000 000 000 y lo hablamos. Te dejo también mi correo , username@domain .com. Venga , hasta luego."
>>> re.sub(r"\s*([\.,])\s*, r"\1", sentence)
'Oye,si te parece quedamos en El Corte Ingl\xc3\xa9s de Nuevos Ministerios este martes,a las 18:30,y me ayudas con las compras,te parece los sof\xc3\xa1s no s\xc3\xa9 si comprarlos en Zara Home o en la web,que es http://zara-home.es.De todas maneras,dame un toque al +00 000 000 000 y lo hablamos.Te dejo tambi\xc3\xa9n mi correo,username@domain.com.Venga,hasta luego.'
>>> print _
Oye,si te parece quedamos en El Corte Inglés de Nuevos Ministerios este martes,a las 18:30,y me ayudas con las compras,te parece los sofás no sé si comprarlos en Zara Home o en la web,que es http://zara-home.es.De todas maneras,dame un toque al +00 000 000 000 y lo hablamos.Te dejo también mi correo,username@domain.com.Venga,hasta luego.
```